# Python Execute class function without instantiating

Tags: python, observer-pattern

I am building a software and am using one class to only store data:

```
class Data():
    data = [1,2,3]
```

Now the data in this class can be accessed and changed from other classes without instantiating the Data class which is exactly what I need.
In order to update the of the software properly I have to call functions in other classes whenever the data changes. I looked at the observer pattern in python but could not get it to work without making data an attribute of the class that's only available when instantiated. In other words all the observer pattern implementations I found required:

```
class Data():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [1,2,3]
```

Obviously, if Data is my publisher/observable it needs to be instantiated once to get the functionality (as far as I understand) but I am looking for an implementation like:

```
class Data():
    data = [1,2,3]
    def __init__(self):
        self.subscribers = {}

    def register(self, who, callback):
        self.subscribers[who] = callback

    def dispatch(self):
        for susbriber, callback in self.subscribers.items():
            callback()
```

For the sake of the example let's use this other class as Subscriber/Observer that can also change the data with another function. As this will be the main class handling the software, this is where I instantiate Data to get the observer behavior. It is important however that I would not have to instantiate it only to get data as data will be changed from a lot of other classes:

```
class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = Data()
        self.data.register(self, self.print_something)
        
    def print_something(self):
        print("Notification Received")

    def change_data(self):
        Data.data.append(100)
```

My question now is, how to automatically send the notification from the Publisher/Observable whenever data gets changed in any way?

I am running python 3.8 on Windows 10.

Comment: Don't use a class if you don't mean to instantiate it. Use a separate module if you want to encapsulate the functions, or create a private class and create one instance of it as a module global.

Comment: Alex Martelli's [Borg pattern](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch05s23.html) provides a way to instantiate multiple instances with shared state.  This might be easier to manage.

Comment: Both of those seem to accomplish what I need in terms of data access and changing. Thank you! Which of these two approaches would make it easier to implement an observer pattern?